# Trying to get Waypoints to work with animate.css on WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Been trying to get results for a few hours but haven't found out how to fix it. I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).waypoint is not a function
    at danzerpress.js:6
    at danzerpress.js:10
```

I've enqueued these files in the functions.php file:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'danzerpress-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/danzerpress.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0');
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-2.1.1', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js', true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-waypoints', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.0/jquery.waypoints.min.js', true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'waypoints-min-js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.5/waypoints.min.js', true);
```

In the danzerpress.js file I have this there where it is telling me the waypoint function is not defined:

```
;(function($){

  // hide our element on page load
  $('#section-1').css('opacity', 0);

  $('#section-1').waypoint(function() {
      $('#section-1').addClass('fadeInLeft');
  }, { offset: '50%' });

})(jQuery);
```

I've been following this guide here and I do have animate.css working just not with waypoints: 
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/05/31/scroll-anmiation-css-waypoints/.

The place I am trying to get it to work is here: https://lifia.bdanzer.com/portal/.

Is there something I am doing completely wrong?

Edit 1: I did just try to remove array('jquery') from danzerpress.js in the enqueue and the console error went away. Seems when you use that WordPress uses the jquery in no conflict mode and you have to enqueue it a certain way. Still not sure if it's working yet.

Comment: Have you tried enqueuing the script(s) in a different order? Let's say, jQuery first, followed by waypoints, then danzerpress

Comment: @SamuelAsor I just tried that but still the same console error

Comment: @SamuelAsor I removed array from danzerpress.js and the errors went away

Comment: Good work. Just so you know, I think you're using an outdated version of waypoints. Version 4.0.1 works with `Waypoints` with a capital **W**.